# How do I remove the favicon from my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, favicon

I have a rails 3.2.6 app and I am using the asset pipeline and I have no favicon.ico but for some reason my app keeps looking for it which is causing problems

```
Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-18 16:20:44 -0400
Processing by PlaylistsController#index as
```

I have no idea what is causing this to get called...there is nothing in my app at all that has the text favicon

My question is, Is there a place in rails that i can tell this to stop?

Here is my head information just in case

```
<head>
  <title>Playlist</title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/common.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/app.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/main.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/editable.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/mutils.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/custom.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="/assets/datatables.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="Pccg3siV8wY7LftMfpyi5rgFArjehQb7g5o1BF7QL1I=" name="csrf-token" />
```

Comment: I think it's your browser that looks for it, not the app.

Comment: is there a way in a rails app to disregard that request....maybe a custom route that does nothing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there's not.

All current, popular browsers (except Seamonkey) make a GET request to `/favicon.ico` themselves, and there's no way to stop them from doing so. If it doesn't exist, they will still request it, and continue to request it; nothing about your application or server can change that.

Rails includes a favicon.ico file with a size of 0 in the `public` folder by default so that instead of sending an HTML 404 page that will never be seen in response, a zero content length response is sent, which (under most production configurations) will be cached and will be faster as it won’t have to be processed by Ruby.

Comment: Andrew, you are a SO legend my friend :)